# use serviceworker to cancel fetch request

Tags: fetch, service-worker, abortcontroller

I have a ServiceWorker that intercepts Fetch Requests. Sometimes, the fetch request is doomed to fail, so the ServiceWorker should cancel it before it even hits the network.

My code looks like:

```js
async function onFetch(event) {
  const { request } = event;

  const result = handleRequest(request)
    .then(someStuff)
    .catch((err) => {
      const ctrl = new AbortController();
      ctrl.abort('request is doomed');

      const cancellation = fetch(request, { signal: ctrl.signal });
      // cancellation is correctly an AbortError DOMException

      // event.respondWith(cancellation); // results in net::ERR_FAILED
      return cancellation;
    });
  
  return event.waitUntil(result);
}
```

A quick experiment without a service worker suggests this should work:

```js
const ctrl = new AbortController();
ctrl.abort('request is doomed');

fetch('http://localhost', { signal: ctrl: signal });
```

In the above experiment, the request in DevTools Network panel is marked "cancelled" and no network request is made.

However, in the ServiceWorker, the request is not cancelled (the abort signal is ignored completely) and it goes out to the network.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide `event.respondWith` a new `Response` (or a `PromiseLike<Response>`), and don't fetch `event.request`, then you effectively cancel the original request.

Depending on the `Response` that you provide, this can have convenient side effects, like cancelling a navigation.  For example you could cancel the fetch request made by any form submission with method `POST`:

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  if (event.request.method === 'POST' && event.request.mode === 'navigate') {
    event.respondWith(new Response(null, { status: 204 }));
  }
});
```

We use HTTP status code [`204 No Content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204) to prevent the navigation here. Depending on the context, other status codes might have more convenient semantics for your use case.